# PySpark python issue: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o80.showString

Tags: python, java, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

hello everyone I am working on PySpark Python and I have the following code to mock for testing. When I run pytest, I return an error and I think it's failing on **show()**. The error points to
*AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326: Py4JJavaError*. Is there an issue with that protocol.py file?

```
import pytest

from src.components.code import code
from src.shared import *
from tests.helper import *


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("spark_session")
def test_company_code(spark_session: SparkSession):
        # Generate mock data
    list_df = spark_session.createDataFrame(
        [
            ("a83905a",),
            ("ghk3945",),
            ("gdss049",),
            ("iuoe043",),
            ("20j48da",),
        ],
        ["id"],
    )

    table_df = spark_session.createDataFrame(
        [
            ("a83905a", "10"),
            ("ghk3945", "15"),
            ("gdss049", "100"),
            ("20j48da", ""),
        ],
        ["id", "code"],
    )

    # Pass mock data to component function
    output = code(table_df, list_df)
    output.show()
```

This is the error after running pytest:

```
answer = 'xro81', gateway_client = <py4j.clientserver.JavaClient object at 0x000002A67F530310>, target_id = 'o80'
name = 'showString'

    def get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id=None, name=None):
        """Converts an answer received from the Java gateway into a Python object.

        For example, string representation of integers are converted to Python
        integer, string representation of objects are converted to JavaObject
        instances, etc.

        :param answer: the string returned by the Java gateway
        :param gateway_client: the gateway client used to communicate with the Java
            Gateway. Only necessary if the answer is a reference (e.g., object,
            list, map)
        :param target_id: the name of the object from which the answer comes from
            (e.g., *object1* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
        :param name: the name of the member from which the answer comes from
            (e.g., *hello* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
        """
        if is_error(answer)[0]:
            if len(answer) > 1:
                type = answer[1]
                value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
                if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
>                   raise Py4JJavaError(
                        "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
                        format(target_id, ".", name), value)
E                   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o80.showString.
E                   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) (LTWX5CG1263K36.principalusa.corp.principal.com executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
E                       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:167)     
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:164)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
E                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
E                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
E                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
E                   Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
E                       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
E                       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:453)
E                       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:139)
E                       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
E                       ... 32 more
E
E                   Driver stacktrace:
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)        
E                       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
E                       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
E                       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)       
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
E                       at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
E                   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
E                       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:167)     
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:164)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
E                       at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
E                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
E                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
E                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
E                   Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
E                       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
E                       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:453)
E                       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:139)
E                       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
E                       ... 32 more

..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326: Py4JJavaError
```

Comment: `Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified` -- looks like either python3 itself, or something it calls, is not in the executor's PATH.

Comment: Yes, I fixed this issue by copying the existing python.exe and renamed it as python3.exe. I guess something requires python 3 instead of python executor?

Comment: Maybe you can check your `spark.pyspark.python` config?

Comment: @mazaneicha How do I do that? Thank you.